# jpa hibernate: generation type sequence always inserts 0 into column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to generate a number like 16857 and have that unique for each entry (note, this column is NOT the primary key). I am using JPA, Hibernate and MySQL.

I tried this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "membernumber_sequence", initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 1)
public class Member implements Model {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "membernumber_sequence")
    private int membernumber;
}
```

However, it always inserts 0 into the column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html):

> The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass **in conjunction with the Id annotation**.

(emphasis mine)

Use a SQL query to get the next sequence value, and initialize the field explicitely.

Comment: jesus, jpa is so damn limited... why not make this possible for all int fields?...